# Is there a Windows 7 alternative to compiz move/resize windows management?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager, window

I know this isn't strictly Ubuntu related, but lately I've had to do some work on a Windows 7 machine and dearly miss the ability to hold alt and move/resize windows the same way it's done on Ubuntu.  Any chance there is a Windows 7 alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a semi-workable solution using the program [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/).  Right now I have it set so that to move a window all I have to do is have the mouse cursor over some part of it and then press right click + middle click.  I can do this by making a "Send Keystrokes" command using the following value: [ALT_DOWN][SPACE][ALT_UP]M[LEFT]

And setting the gesture itself to "MBUTTON_DOWN".

You could probably do something similar for resizing.